# Printing a member from a pointer struct

Tags: c, function, pointers, struct

I have a struct like so

```
typedef struct Thing{
    int att;
} Thing;

Thing *newThing(){
    Thing *t;
    t = (Thing *)(malloc(sizeof(Thing)));
    thing->att = 0;
    return t;
}
```

I have a printThing function that tries to print the value in att like so:

```
void printThing(Thing *t){
    printf("%d", t->att);
}
```

However this results in a segmentation fault but I can print the correct value in main the same way. What am I doing wrong?

```
int main(){
    Thing *t1 = readThing();//This works
    printf("%d", t1->att); //This also works
    printThing(t1); //Segmentation fault

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How do you allocate memory for your struct? Give as a minimal complete example!

Comment: If the first `printf()` works, yes.

Comment: @gsamaras edited to show how memory is allocated.

Comment: @DavidBowling I can print the values just fine in main

Comment: For starters, you should be checking whether `malloc()` has returned a null pointer in `newThing()`.

Comment: Is `printThing()` declared/defined before use in `printThing(t1);`  This post still lacks a clear set of code to exhibit the problem - just snippets.

Comment: @justaquery, @DavidBowling is right:  ALWAYS check the return value of `malloc`

Comment: Still no [MCVE].... The `newThing()` function is never called in the posted code, and the `readThing()` function is called, but not posted.

Answer (score 1):

The problem may be here:

```
Thing *newThing(){
    Thing *t;
    t = (Thing *)(malloc(sizeof(Thing)));
    thing->att = 0;
    return t;
}
```

since you allocate memory dynamically and make `t` point to it, but you do `thing->att = 0;` and not `t->att = 0;`, as you should.

Comment: Yeah well seen !

Comment: I would expect a compilation error, unless a non-C compiler is used.

Comment: Not if `thing` is declared somewhere that is not shown here @chux. YaaSuka, you would have seen it as well, I just saw the edit earlier! ;)

Comment: True, yet the code is printing a member that is not assigned.  Even though UB, I'd expect random printed data and not a seg fault.  Well UB is UB and OP's post remains incomplete and it veracity is in doubt.